# Using Dispatcher to unblock Wpf Ui

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher, event-dispatch-thread

I am working on windows app which generates various results of testing. The UI provides a button `Results` which has various methods as event handlers. These methods are provided by an API module. The module fetches the data from warehouse and then displays it to the user. 
The API call is asynchronous.

But UI gets blocked once the button is clicked. 
After quite some readings , I came to know that Dispatcher helps in running a process in background . Dispatcher can be invoked/call only by the UI thread. 
How can I implement dispatcher to keep the UI away from being blocked?

The function in c# looks something like this

```
private async void get_results(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      List<resultsummary> data = new List<resultsummary>();
      if(id==plan_id)
        {
           data= await getdata.getsummary(id, name);
         }           
}
```

Edit:-

This is my understanding of async and await in the above code. But it gives an error `cannot await`. The `getdata` class is in differnet namespace and the method `getsummary` is defined in that space.

The main objective is to unblock the UI and how to go about this using Dispatcher technique?

Comment: +1 @HighCore. Again... loving your work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a `Dispatcher` to do what you want. In order to fetch data on a background thread and then pass that data from the background thread to the UI thread, you can use the [`Task` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Task.Factory.StartNew((Func<YourDataType>)delegate()
{
    // Fetch data on background thread here (return YourDataType, whatever that is)
    return DataAccessClass.GetData();
}).ContinueWith((Task<YourDataType> task) =>
{
    // Update controls with result on UI thread here
    YourUiProperty = task.Result;
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Obviously, you'll need to replace the `YourDataType` type with whatever your data type is.

Comment: +1. It's also worth mentioning that using C# 5's `async / await` features this code is drastically more elegant and beautiful.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that not everyone uses .NET 4.5 yet and... well... I guess I'm just getting lazy in my old age... and it *is* midnight. But yeah, valid point, well mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Action`...

Put your code in an `Action` like this"

```
Action action = () =>
{
    // your code...
};
```

assume that you have a label to show result

```
myLabel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
```